# Is correct start Kotlin coroutines from Activity java file?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-gradle-3.0

Android Studio 3.4

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

in Kotlin file: **TransportService.kt**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import retrofit2.Response


  @JvmStatic
        fun doLoginFromJava(
            email: String,
            password: String,
            isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false
        ): CompletableFuture<Response<*>> = GlobalScope.future {
            login(email, password, isCustomtHandle)
        }


suspend fun login(email: String, password: String, isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false): Response<*> {
            val json = JsonObject()
            json.addProperty("email", email);
            json.addProperty("password", password);
            suspend fun execOperation(): Response<*> = myRestClient.login(json)
            return runOperation(isCustomtHandle, ::execOperation)
}
```

Her api interface:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.POST

/*
  Notice we are calling the suspend method in order to wait until our asynchronous operation has finished.
  Awaits for completion of this value without blocking a thread and resumes when deferred computation is complete,
  returning the resulting value (e.g. after 3 seconds) or throwing the corresponding exception if the deferred was cancelled.
*/
interface TangoRestClient {

    @POST("/login")
    suspend fun login(@Body body: JsonElement) : Response<JsonElement>  


}
```

use this from Kotlin activity file (**TradersActivity.kt**):

```
import android.app.Activity;
class TradersActivity :Activity

    private fun loadData() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val response: Response<*> = TransportService.login("email", "password")
             if (response.get().isSuccessful()) {
                     Toast.makeText(context, "Success response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

Nice it's work fine.

OK.

But I also have java file that need to use same logic. **And which I'm not able to convert to Kotlin for now**.

I need to start Kotlin coroutine from java and start method `doLoginFromJava` in **IO** (async) thread.
Also the result must in **UI** thread to show toast.

So I try this in java file **LoginActivity.java** (I call method `doLoginFromJava`)

```
 import android.app.Activity;
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

  try {
        CompletableFuture<Response<?>> response = TransportService.doLogin("email", "pass", false);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "login_response = " + response);
        if (response.get().isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success reponse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The question is:
Is this correct equivalent of Kotlin code?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not equivalent since `response.get()` will block the UI thread.

You simply won't be able to replicate the functionality of coroutines as a single method since they are designed to deal with "interruptions" in the execution during which other code may run. You will need to implement the normal `Handler` and callback-based solution to deal with data that is available at some point in the future.

However you might want to consider implementing the part that requires coroutines in kotlin and then just calling it from the `LoginActivity`, essentially slowly moving the implementation over as required.